# Implicit Trapezoidal Rule

Tags: numerical-methods

Integrate $y' = \sin(y)$, $y_0 = 2$; using $h = 0.1$ with the implicit Trapezoidal rule, to compute $y_1$ within approximate relative error $e<10^{-5}$.

I first tried to apply the Trapezoidal rule which then resulted in an implicit equation. To solve that, then I tried going by Newton's method and it is still not working well for me. So, I assumed an initial approximation $y_n^{(0)}$ and iterated the whole equation to make it converge to $y_n$, but again I am getting stuck somewhere.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your definition of $y_1$?  Is it $y(x_0+h)$ or $y(x_0+1)$ or something else completely different?

Comment: It is $y(x_0 + h)$ only.

Comment: Please, if you could document how you applied the Newton method, what function, what derivative or its approximation.